# How to refactor code using styled components in react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to refactor code for the styled components using react and typescript.

i have two link  black and blue sharing same css and some style differ.

below is the code,

```
return (
    <Wrapper>
        <ButtonLink a="someurl">
            black
        </ButtonLink>
        <ButtonLink a="url">
            blue
        </ButtonLink>
    </Wrapper>
);


const ButtonLink = styled.a`
    border: none;
    background: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`;
```

Now for the black link i want to add background-color: black and for blue link i want to add the background-color blue.

how can i add these styles to those two links using styled components. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: you have to pass the color as a prop to the ButtonLink styled component then conditionally change the background color

Comment: @someuser2491 Thanks for `validate` my answer. Can you also please `upvote` all useful answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add add the color as a props of your `ButtonLink` component. But don't forget to add the interface for it since you are using TypeScript:

```
return (
    <Wrapper>
        <ButtonLink color="black" a="someurl">
            black
        </ButtonLink>
        <ButtonLink color="blue" a="url">
            blue
        </ButtonLink>
    </Wrapper>
);

interface ButtonLinkProps {
    color: string
}  

const ButtonLink = styled.a<ButtonLinkProps>`
    color: ${props => props.color}
    border: none;
    background: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass properties as a props to your components, for example

```
<ButtonLink color="red" href="#">Red</ButtonLink>
```

```
const ButtonLink = styled.a`
  ...,
  color: ${props => props.color}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use props in your styled component

```
const ButtonLink = styled.a`
    border: none;
    background: ${props => props.bgColor};
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;`
```

Then pass in the props like this

```
return (
  <Wrapper>
     <ButtonLink a="someurl" bgColor="black">
         black
     </ButtonLink>
     <ButtonLink a="url" bgColor="blue">
         blue
     </ButtonLink>
  </Wrapper>
);
```

Alternatively if you don't want to pass in props you could extend the initial ButtonLink component

```
const ButtonLink = styled.a`
    border: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;`


const BlueButtonLink = styled(ButtonLink)`
    background-color: #0000FF;`

const BlackButtonLink = styled(ButtonLink)`
    background-color: #000;`


return (
  <Wrapper>
     <BlackButtonLink a="someurl">
         black
     </BlackButtonLink>
     <BlueButtonLink a="url" >
         blue
     </BlueButtonLink>
  </Wrapper>
);
```